# Azure ad display bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, advertising

There is a bug with the Azure ad that is currently being displayed on the main site.

Some of the HTML code is being shown in the ad.

OS: Windows 10
Browser: Chrome Version 61.0.3163.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)

[image: Azure ad bug]

Comment: Seems to be an error with the creative. Will investigate and try to fix.

Comment: meta.SE [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301587/advert-showing-some-markup-not-rendering-correctly)

Comment: By checking the below image, I think microsoft want a full width ad but they paid for a sidebar ad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Good catch! This was due to an error in set up. When trying to append a click-macro we had a superfluous quotation mark in the creative tag. In addition, an incorrect creative tag-- a leaderboard-- was associated with a sidebar.

Easy to fix, and a great reminder that our typos are visible by many!

Thank you and we appreciate your eagle eyes! While we have a bunch of people working to ensure that [the transition from Adzerk to DFP](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301524/all-sites-will-be-switching-ad-servers-on-october-1) goes as smooth as possible, there will be bumps in the road. Like this one.

Thank you again!

Comment: Ad-bug-finder would make one heck of a rare badge.

Answer (score 8):

Confirmed on Chrome latest.

Possible related to the size of the image being used not being compatible with the sidebar requirements:

> https://s0.2mdn.net/6992662/AZR_FY17-Variation2-TryAzureFree-EN_US_728x90_BAN_Jun-14.jpg

[image]

HTML that renders the ad if it's of any use:

```
<div class="GoogleActiveViewClass" id="DfaVisibilityIdentifier_440458037" style="">
    <a target="_blank" 
       href="https://adclick.g.doubleclick.net/pcs/click?xai=AKAOjsuRStAIS1gM_Y0UoqNYGWfXx8nfJXvmwGdClLUavLIEoDSafUPakScyDwS5kl9fD7_P5W_QLqIzE8df_aosqluPCjh5eafONaJ824MvQzoudDAqOB1BxmnDjtrNjwEZ5oYwxg&amp;sig=Cg0ArKJSzAkQ3XvZvMbK&amp;urlfix=1&amp;adurl=https://adclick.g.doubleclick.net/pcs/click%3Fxai%3DAKAOjst51snenNtpe_OM2aXSOF4QXd2tdmkzCaS9iqqwx7GwRLrCjefhfme-WkBdVbO_4PNfwXJRUE6fo0mPi4t0Plf1R9aN1S4kkZ6XwiH1Y6MgGME-q2OOnSs4BTZehwqT9hptaKZYHDrfshb1967L-EuObS4doHVlIGhBeSda1V-rnwPa-aTFcHLPYgnPObG_mxWIXqbirJM_ajSH5wAL7oXanNYnn3TnMlYI8z4pAlxM8H_NcHPQQRHbgMVzIBooxbjLK2Zekr1vl_Dhqg%26sig%3DCg0ArKJSzJbd0dY6yE05EAE%26urlfix%3D1%26adurl%3Dhttps://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/free/%253FAID622763_OLA_20367618_206196396_93438816">
        <img src="https://s0.2mdn.net/6992662/AZR_FY17-Variation2-TryAzureFree-EN_US_728x90_BAN_Jun-14.jpg" 
             alt="Advertisement" border="0" width="728" height="90">
    </a>
</div>
```

Seems to be just showing the placeholder text because the image isn't the required size:

[image]